# How to create multiple columns efficiently in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance, apply, multiple-columns

I am trying to add around 2000 columns in a dataframe having around 450k records using certain conditions, however its taking a lot of time. Can someone provide time efficient solution for this. Sample code is like this -

```
dict1={x:x for x in range(2000)}
Data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10000,size=(450000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
for i in range(1,2000):
    Data[f'A_{i}']= Data['A'].apply(lambda x: max(0,min(5000,x) -dict1[i]))
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MRE] with example input and expected output? A vectorized solution can easily be extrapolated to a larger use case.

Comment: Is `max(0, min(5000))` your real condition?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny If you run the first two lines, that's my input. I am actually working on client site so cant provide exact details but yeah its on similar line. I am expecting to have 2000 columns added like A_1, A_2...A_2000 with the condition I have provided

Comment: @Corralien Yeah just that 5000 would be pass through another variable and values might differ, so for sake of simplicity I have put 5000 instead of variable

Comment: Its better to 1) prepare all new columns data in list/dict. 2) create dataframe out of it 3) merge this dataframe with the one you started with.

Comment: @dankal444 Can you provide example on how to do 1st step of create data in dict for my problem?

Comment: @AbhishekDwivedi if you provide minimal reproducible example Micheal talked about, then yes

Answer (score 0):

This code is around 250x times faster.  I was using:

- `int16` to decrease RAM usage
- `np.clip` instead of slow applying `min` and `max`
- broadcasting (reshaping to `(-1, 1) and vice versa)
- creating dataframe out of all columns instead of appending each column iteratively

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from copy import deepcopy

# converting to int16 everywhere to decrease RAM usage, you can remove it
dict1={x:x for x in range(2000)}
Data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10000,size=(450000, 4)).astype(np.int16), columns=list('ABCD'))
Data2 = deepcopy(Data) # copying data for later comparison, you can remove it

# # OP version, only 20 columns
for i in range(0, 20):  # fixed this for you, because you started iterating from 1 instead of 0
    Data[f'A_{i}']= Data['A'].apply(lambda x: max(0,min(5000,x) -dict1[i]))

# new version, 2000 columns:
# using np.clip that is much faster than DataFrame.apply
Data_A_values_clipped = np.clip(Data['A'].values, None, 5000)
all_dict_values = np.array(list(dict1.values())[:2000]).astype(np.int16)

# using broadcastring is much faster than iterating
new_columns = np.clip(Data_A_values_clipped.reshape(1, -1) - all_dict_values.reshape(-1, 1), 0, None)

new_columns = {f'A_{i}': new_columns[i] for i in range(2000)}
# creating new dataframe out of new data and merging with the
Data2 = pd.concat([Data2, pd.DataFrame(new_columns)], axis=1)

# I checked for 20 columns, is ok:
# assert np.all(Data.values == Data2.values)
# print('well done')
```